# Detect first log of user

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I'm realizing a theme with liferay using velocity. I would like to add some functions to the theme homepage only in the case the user logs in the portal for the first time. 
How can I use velocity (portal_normal.vm) to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by **@Olaf Kock** it is not suggested to use the business logic in the theme section.

But, If you want to do it anyway then Liferay provides a set of Velocity Variables that can be accessed in the Themes. Which includes the `User` details too.

These are some of the `User` related Variables available globally in themes,

**$user_id,$is_default_user,$user_first_name,$user_middle_name .... $user_login_ip, $user_last_login_ip**

You can check out more at : `themes\_unstyled\templates\init.vm` inside ROOT.WAR.

So, For your specific purpose here you can use `$user_last_login_ip`. If the value is null then it would be the first time the user has logged into the portal.So, use this inside the `portal_normal.vm`,

```
#if (!$user_last_login_ip)
 ... do stuff here if the variable is null
#end
```

And, Alternately you can fetch the User last login date using and check `null` to ensure whether it is his first login,

```
#if (!$user.getLastLoginDate())
 ... do stuff here if the variable is null
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add this to the theme. Rather have a separate [custom LoginAction](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/perform-a-custom-action-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) for this. This will be executed on every login (you can choose pre- or post-login, I'm assuming that post-login will be appropriate) and should find some more information than I linked on this topic all over the net.

A theme is made for look&feel and should not contain any business logic - especially not when it's for a one-off purpose.